# Allan Deviation Algorithm

Tags: programming, algorithm, procedural-programming

I am trying to write my own Allan Deviation calculator in Mathematica using the definition,
$$\sigma(\tau)^{2}=\frac{1}{2M-2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(\bar{y}_{i+1} - \bar{y}_{i})^{2}\text{.}$$
Where the $\bar{y}$ are mean partitioned data for some multiple of measurement time $\tau$, and $M$ is the length of the number of $(\bar{y}_{i+1} - \bar{y}_{i})^{2}$ associated with each $\tau$. I made a toy model of partitioning the data that I am happy with, but I am struggling to extending it to the next step, which is simply summing the $(\bar{y}_{i+1} - \bar{y}_{i})^{2}$ for each $\tau$. The toy model is:

```
NumberPoints = 64;
IndexData = Range [NumberPoints];

Do[
  Print["________________τ=", j];
  Do[
   Print[
    "(MEAN", Partition[IndexData, j][[2 i]], "-", "MEAN", 
    Partition[IndexData, j][[2 i - 1]], 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)"
    ],
   {i, 1, (NumberPoints/(j*2))}
   ],
  {j, 1, NumberPoints/4}
  ];
```

If I try, for the next step:

```
Do[
  Clear[BlockMeanDifferenceList];
  BlockMeanDifferenceList = {};
  Do[
   BlockMeanDifferenceList = (
     Mean[Partition[RandomData, τ][[2 i]]] - 
     Mean[Partition[RandomData, τ][[2 i - 1]]]
   )^2;
   AppendTo[σ, (1/(2 Length[BlockMeanDifference] - 2)*Total[BlockMeanDifference])^(1/2)];,
   {i, 1, (NumberOfPoints/(τ*2))}
   ];,
  {τ, 1, NumberOfPoints/4}
  ];
```

My sigma list is returned for zero in all elements...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing a few things, e.g. the initialization of `σ`. Also, what's the difference between `BlockMeanDifferenceList` and `BlockMeanDifference`, and `NumberOfPoints` vs `NumberPoints` (I assume they're the same?)? Instead of `Clear` inside a loop, consider using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html). And finally, your code seems to contradict your formula: One has differences of the form $y_2-y_1,y_3-y_2,...$ while the other one has $y_2-y_1,y_4-y_3$ (i.e. disjoint)

Comment: @Mathe172 Sorry, you are right, `σ={}` should be included. and `NumberOfPoints` and `NumberPoints` is the same thing -- I was just sloppy. As for the disjoint, I don't see where that is as the indexing is the same for both the toy model showing the partitioning and for the real attempt?

Comment: I meant the difference between code and formula (the one you provide), not between the two code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Below an attempt to implement your formula as I understand it (the prefactor is missing, as I'm not quite sure what $M$ should be) - please do correct me if I misunderstood something.

```
avar[data_, τ_] := Total[
  (
    Subtract @@@ (*get the difference of the pairs*)
     Partition[ (*create overlapping subsequences of length 2*)
      Mean /@ Partition[data, τ], (*partition data into block and calculate mean*)
      2, 1
      ]
    )^2
  ]
```

With this, `avar[Array[Subscript[a, #] &, 16], 4]` yields:

[image: Output of function]

If you don't want overlapping differences, simply remove the `,1` in the outer partition (this controls the offset of the individual sublists)

#### Update

Since you tagged this [procedural-programming](/questions/tagged/procedural-programming), here is an approach more closely based on yours (it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with your attempt specifically, as there are still a few obvious typos - see my comment)

```
avarProc[data_, τ_] := Module[
  {
   partitions = Partition[data, τ],
   σ = {},
   diff
   },
  Do[
   diff = (Mean@partitions[[i + 1]] - Mean@partitions[[i]])^2;
   AppendTo[σ, diff],
   {i, 1, Length@data/τ - 1}
   ];
  Total@σ
  ]
```

This produces the same output as the above. Again, this uses overlapping sublists. To change this, simply take your indexing and loop bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain a little what `Module` does? I have not come across this yet

Comment: It basically allows you to introduce local variables. For a more detailed (and accurate) description, see [this great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/36508) and the documenation [here (`Module`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) and [here (Scoping constructs)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html)